# how to transfer data from Node-RED (message.payload) to Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: node-red, azure-blob-storage

I have a python script that retrieves data from a smart plug (to monitor energy consumption from devices). My end goal is to analyze this data with Stream Analytics and therefore I need to send it to a database in Microsoft Azure.

Right now I am running the python script on Node-RED and the output comes into message.payload. I want to send this data to Blob Storage and for that I am using this node https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-azure-blob-storage

The problem is that I am getting this error:

```
4 Apr 11:57:51 - [info] [Save Blob:Azure Save Blob Storage] Uploading blob...
4 Apr 11:57:51 - [info] [Save Blob:Azure Save Blob Storage] Container 'container5' ready for blob creation
4 Apr 11:57:52 - [info] [Save Blob:Azure Save Blob Storage] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'Thu Apr  4 11:57:51 2019
21 mA
229867 mV
0 mW
556 Wh
```

Those values ( 21 mA, 229867 mV, 0 mW,556 Wh) are what I want to save in Blob Storage. I know that this node can connect to my Blob Storage account because that container5 is being created every time I press inject. But the data is not coming anywhere. Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: It looks like it's trying to find a file that's named by your data – you may need to save that data to a disk file first, then upload that disk file.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply! The data is being measured and printed every 5 seconds. So you suggest that I store the printed data in a txt file or something? Isn't that gonna take a lot of space? I am working on a Raspberry Pi and this program should run 24/7

Comment: If you always save to, say, `/tmp/sensor-data.txt`, it'll just overwrite a single file (and `/tmp` is usually a memory-backed file system, so it won't wear out the SD card either).

Comment: ... Ah, though in that case the Azure Blob Storage node will always overwrite the same file in the blob storage too. Well, generate a filename such as `/tmp/sensor-data-(TIMESTAMP).txt`, write to that, then delete the file after the upload is complete?

Comment: Okay, sounds good. I am still a beginner but it seems like your idea is doable even if it takes me 3 years to implement it. This means I should create this file in my python code, then read the values from the smart plug and ouput them, store them in the file (which allows the transfer to blob storage) and then delete the file? And this should happen every 5 seconds?

Comment: Sorry, I entirely missed that you're using Python too :) In that case, just use the Azure Blob Storage client... Let me just make that an answer for you :)

Comment: Ignore the python, that is totally irrelevant to this question, the input is a Node-RED message

Comment: @hardillb No, the _actual_ question is how to get this data to Azure Blob Storage. With just Node-RED and the linked Azure Blob Storage node, there's no other way to upload than to go through a disk file, and that's suboptimal for OP's use case.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're already using Python, it'd be much easier to write the blob from within Python using the official Azure Blob Storage client.

Once you have installed the client (e.g. `pip install azure-storage-blob`), something like this should do (dry-coded, YMMV):

```py
import io
import datetime
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

my_data = '''
Thu Apr  4 11:57:51 2019
21 mA
229867 mV
0 mW
556 Wh
'''


# Will generate something like 'stats-20190404-110930'
filename = 'stats-%s' % datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')

# Grab a reference to the block blob storage service
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(
    account_name='azure-storage-account-name',
    sas_token='access-token-from-azure-access-keys-page',
)

# Upload directly from the text you have
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_text(
    container_name='azure-storage-container-name',
    blob_name=filename,
    text=my_data,
)
```

It would be much better to save the data in a structured format like JSON, though, so you don't need to parse this custom text format anywhere, and use the ISO8601 standard for the date too:

```py
import json
import datetime

data = {
  'date': datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
  'voltage_mv': 229867,
  'current_ma': 21,
  'power_mw': 0,
  'energy_wh': 556,
}

my_data = json.dumps(data)  # encode into JSON

# (the same upload dance as before)
```

Comment: Python is irrelevant to the question, the problem is to do with how the OP is driving the Azure Node-RED node

Comment: With the Azure Node-RED node, as it currently is, it can only write from a single disk file to a single blob on Azure, and that's not useful for OP's use case if they need to accumulate measurements.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for your solution. I am trying to install the azure storage blob like you told me, but I get (many) message errors like : Failed building wheel for cryptography,  Failed cleaning build dir for cryptography,   Failed building wheel for cffi. Any ideas? Do I need to install azure too? Cause I tried to install azure before installing blob storage but I also got errors

Comment: Okay I wrote "sudo" before the command and it should be installed now. I will try your solution and give an update :)

Comment: I get the following message: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hs110-martatest.py", line 12, in <module>
    from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
ImportError: No module named 'azure'`

Comment: @xoani The Python interpreter you're using to run your code doesn't have the module, then, implying the `sudo pip install ...` installed it into a different interpreter environment – installing modules (correctly) is out of scope for this question, but see https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Comment: @AKX the problem is that I can't try your solution without this package thing (I don't really know what it is, I am sorry). Am I searching in the right place? https://pypi.org/search/?q=azure

Comment: You may want to try `sudo pip3 install azure-storage-blob` if you're running your script with Python 3. Or if your script is in a virtualenv, you would need to install `azure-storage-blob` in that virtualenv as well.